# High gain op-amp, but still being able to get 0V output

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, switching, multiplexer

I'm not a learned electrical engineer, so all my knowledge is self-taught and thus a little spotty. I hope you guys can help.

Here is my problem:

My goal is to switch between ROWPIN 1-4 (there are actually more, but lets keep it simple for this example) quite fast and at a voltage-level of 3.3V (on 0V respectively.) To do so, my idea was, to use a MUX for the switching and op-amps with a high gain value behind them. The op-amps are supposed to (1.) pull the voltage level to 3.3V, since the MUX's output level is more around 2.7V and (2.) to make switching faster since the op-amp will pull up the voltage to its supply-voltage, as soon as the MUX starts to ramp up the voltage at the output pin.

An obvious solution would be to just leave out the op-amp and hope that the MUX is fast enough.

I would still likd to know if there is a different solution. Is there a way to achieve "true" 0V at the inactive outputs of the MUX, in a way that the op-amp doesn't react to it?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to drive a matrix keypad, is that right? Where do you get 2.7V? From measurement? Where does the 3.3V output go? I'm not sure that you even want an op amp to do what you need it to do. A gain stage like you're showing here amplifies the mux output linearly, and it's just a coincidence that the gain is so high that the output slams as close to the 3.3V rail as the op amp can go. Better would be to use a buffer IC or a comparator, but I don't think that's really what you need for the application.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good use-case for opamps.  If the voltage out of the MUX truly isn't high enough, consider having it drive the gate of a MOSFET and have it switch between the rails for you.

Comment: @drkntz It's for a matrix sensor array. So pretty similar to a matrix keyboard. 
I measured the 2.7 V at the output of the MUX (I0-I7). Thanks on the feedback with the OpAmps!

Comment: @VictorMas - Hi, Stack Exchange has different rules & etiquette than typical forums - see the [tour] & [help] explaining the Q&A approach. You have received answers to your original question. Then you posted an "answer" which asked follow-up questions, as people sometimes do on typical forums. However that is not allowed here, because new questions are not allowed to be written as *answers*. Also it is too late to change your original question to extend it, since it would make existing answers to your original question look incomplete.

Comment: (continued) Instead, please follow [this article](/help/someone-answers) to effectively close *this* question. Then if you have a follow-up question, please ask it separately and include a link to *this* question for context (although any new question should be self-contained, so it should include enough information that readers are *not required* to read *this* question to understand a new one). || Your "answer" was deleted, since it was asking new questions, which is against how this site works, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve "true" 0V at the inactive outputs of the MUX, in a way that the OpAmp doesn't react to it?

The MUX is basically a set of switches that connects/disconnects the inputs (I0-to-I7) to/from the common rail (output or Y):

[image]

When you select an input with S[0,1,2] the respective switch closes and connects the selected rail to the common rail. The rest become practically floating.

So if you want to keep them at 0V potential when they are disconnected from the common rail, the simplest thing you can do is to tie them to 0V with a resistor (pull-down):

[image]

In your circuit the common rail is 3.3V so this will not cause any problems when an input is connected to the common rail because it's going to be still 3.3V.

The value of the resistors depends on your application i.e. if your application requires really low power consumption then you can keep the resistors at hundreds of kiloohms (or even a few megaohms) but the higher they are the slower the response you'll get. The lower they are the faster response but the consumption will become more of a problem i.e. you don't want your MUX to have large currents flowing through. For your application 1k to 10k should be fine. Try and find an acceptable value.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to read the diagram. I'm happy that I learned something new today :D

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to process a signal that switches between 2.7 V and GND to make a signal that switches from 3.3 V to GND, that can be done with any CMOS gate, buffer, inverter, etc.  The input transition level is approx. Vcc/2, and around that the gate acts as a comparator.

But . . .

It looks like the signals into the opamps switch between 3.3 V (or 2.7 V) and an open circuit.  Not good.  You need to add pull-down resistors to the mux outputs.  There is a trade-off here.  The lower the resistance, the faster the unselected outputs will drop to 0 V.  But, the lower the resistance, the more the selected output's voltage will be attenuated.  Life is choice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I didn't know I had to use pull-down resistors, so that's an important thing I've learned :D 

I also learned that the MUX seems to be pretty fast and input voltage into the array isn't to important, I just need to know its value. So I might just skip the whole OpAmp stage.

Answer (score 0):

Your multiplexer is an *analog* multiplexer. It essentially acts as a switch between your Y input and your output, as given in the other responses. When the output is disabled, the pin is "floating" and neither driven high nor low, and is subject to whatever system noise is present. If you really need sharp transitions between the rails, you need a *digital* device (decoder). This device uses digital logic to drive the output either high or low, and never leaves it in a floating state.

For example, if you use the 74HC238, you can drive each output high or low (within 0.1V of 3.3V and 0V) if you pull G1 and G0 to ground and G2 to 3.3V. The transition speed should be <20ns, plenty fast for your application I think.

[image: Truth Table from TI Datasheet]

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct138.pdf